# Examples of wavy functions needed

Tags: graphing-functions

There are many functions, the graphs of which appear as waves on X-axis of Cartesian plane, with ever increasing amplitude as $x$ approaches $–\infty$. eg. $y=x^n \sin(x)\cos(x)$ Can you provide me with some more examples of such functions?

Comment: Can somebody please fix the formula? This is my first time with MathJax and I'm unable to do so.

Comment: Here's a good [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  One thing that helped me a lot is when you see a formula on this site that you don't know how to format, you can right click it it, then choose Show Math as... TeX commands to see how to write it.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions like$$e^{kx} \sin bx$$  and $$e^{kx} \cos bx$$ with different values of $k$ and $b$ are other examples of wavy functions.

Comment: Can you please provide examples where the amplitude increases as x approaches –∞?

Comment: $e^{-2x} cos x$ is such a function.  When you let $k<0$ the amplitude goes to infinity as $x\to -\infty$

Comment: @SumantChopde. If you replace $e^{kx}$ with $\cosh(kx) = \frac12(e^{kx}+e^{-kx})$ or $\sinh(kx) = \frac12(e^{kx}-e^{-kx})$ then you get a "wavy function" with an amplitude that tends to infinity at both ends, both as $x \to +\infty$ and as $x \to -\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

1. $\frac12(e^x + e^{-x}) \sin x$
2. $|x| \sin x$
3. $\ln|x| \sin x$
4. $\sqrt{1+x^2} \sin x$
5. $e^{e^x+e^{-x}} \sin x$